PTP4L Not working as expected after changing domainNumber
PTP Not working as expected after changing domainNumber.
I am trying to send ptp frames from ptp4l (version 4.3) using the following command:

This works as expected
sudo ptp4l -i eth0 -m -2 -S -P --logSyncInterval=-1 --transportSpecific=0x1 --follow_up_info=1 --ptp_dst_mac=01:80:C2:00:00:0E --p2p_dst_mac=01:80:C2:00:00:0E --domainNumber=0

(--domainNumber not mandatory, default is 0)

This does not work:
sudo ptp4l -i eth0 -m -2 -S -P --logSyncInterval=-1 --transportSpecific=0x1 --follow_up_info=1 --ptp_dst_mac=01:80:C2:00:00:0E --p2p_dst_mac=01:80:C2:00:00:0E --domainNumber=1

Only Pdelay_request is sent, no sync and followup message

However, it works again when removing --follow_up_info=1, like
sudo ptp4l -i eth 0 -m -2 -S -P --logSyncInterval=-1 --transportSpecific=0x1 --ptp_dst_mac=01:80:C2:00:00:0E --p2p_dst_mac=01:80:C2:00:00:0E --domainNumber=1



Can someone explain what is happening here?
